# Distances of points in unit square to N random anchor points

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, geometric-probability

Assume that N points are distributed uniformly randomly within the unit square, and call these points anchor points.

What is the mean, mean minimum, and mean maximum distance of a point randomly chosen within the square that is not an anchor point to its closest anchor point?

Comment: The first N point is fixed and known and the last point is randomly chosen? Or the N first one is randomly chosen and the last one is considered fixed?

Comment: Ideally all points are randomly chosen. But I would like to vary the density of the first N ones eventually, so you may consider the "test" or "last" point fixed. I have since edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: What is meant by "mean minimum" and "mean maximum" distance between a chosen point and its *closest* anchor point?

Comment: My thinking is that if there are N points and you introduce one more at random then (a) that point is bound to have ONE closest neighbour and (b) its distance to it will  probably lie within some distance bounds, i.e. for the sake of argument $[0,\sqrt{2}]$

Comment: I don't think a closed-form solution for "mean minimum" exists. For the "mean maximum", the problem is 10 times harder.

Comment: Thank you for giving this the thought that you have. I have since added the relaxation of simply the "mean".